# Solve $\int \frac{x+1}{x^2-2x+5}dx$

Tags: integration

I need help to understand what's wrong with my integral.

This is the result from wolframalpha, mine is very different: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint+%5Cfrac%7Bx%2B1%7D%7Bx%5E2-2x%2B5%7D

$$\int \frac{x+1}{x^2-2x+5}$$

Numerator < Denominator so I tried to use partial fractions:

$$D[x^2-2x+5] = 2x -2$$

$$\frac{x+1}{x^2-2x+5} = \frac{A(2x-2)+B}{x^2-2x+5}$$

I get:

$$2Ax -2A + B = x + 1$$

So:

$$A = \frac{1}{2}$$
$$B = 2$$

Then:
$$ \int \frac{\frac{1}{2}(2x-2)+2}{x^2-2x+5} = \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{2x-2+2}{x^2-2x+5}$$

Now I have 2 integrals:

$$ \frac{1}{2} \big[ \int \frac{2x-2}{x^2-2x+5} + 2 \int \frac{1}{x^2-2x+5} \big]$$

So my result is:

$$ \frac{1}{2} \big[ ln|x^2-2x+5| +2ln|x^2-2x+5| \big]$$

Where is the error?

Comment: The first of your two integrals has been carefully constructed to be a logarithm - but the second isn't. You need to consider the numerator $(x-1)^2+4$ for the second one and get a different type of standard integral.

Comment: You cannot get twice the same result. Compute the derivative of what you wrote and check. It is not correct. For the second term  Mark Bennet gave you the hint.

Comment: Please, $dx$ !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int\dfrac{dx}{x^2-2x+5}=\int\dfrac{dx}{(x-1)^2+2^2}=\dfrac12\arctan\dfrac{x-1}2+C$$

Answer (score 2):

The error is in the last step:

$$ \int \frac{1}{x^2-2x+5} \, dx \neq \ln|x^2-2x+5| +C$$

(Think about how you deal with the first term: It involves a substitution $u = (x-1)^2$).

To deal with this term, write

$$\frac{1}{x^2-2x+5} = \frac{1}{(x-1)^2 + 4}$$

and use trigonometric substitution.